Getting response from thank you email in second round of interview
I have second round faculty interview and send thank you notes to Dean of the Dept., chair of the committee and chair of the Dept. The first two replied me, even though I did not expect the Dean replies me. Is it a good sign?
Thank you!

Sorry, I know it's hard to be in such an uncertain state, but we cannot tell you anything useful. From the linked question: 'Do not waste time trying to read the tea leaves (e.g., "Hmm, they said 'we will let you know'...is that a good sign?"); this is fruitless. You should continue your job search until you have accepted a written offer.'

Well, of course it's not a bad sign. But you can't read too much into it. When we're hiring and a candidate sends me a thank you note, I always respond. It's just a polite thing to do. The fact that I responded doesn't tell them whether they're the top choice or already ruled out. We would never communicate that till the search was over.
